# Black-Translucent in ios PWA does not work

Tags: html, ios, flutter, progressive-web-apps

I made a Pwa with **Flutter Web** and I set as color on the whole project: # 8C3144. On Index.html I have black-translucent so also the status-bar in ios became # 8C3144, but it continues to **remain black.** I don't understand what I need to change, I **don't** think the problem is in the Flutter project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#8C3144">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="follow crash">
  
  

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="crash">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>Crash</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-core.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
 
  </script>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

In the in index.html add this in the head:

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: #79d279;
}
</style>
```